# GridView Set Fixed Column Number

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to set the number of `GridView` columns?

For example, I have a `GridView` which should always have 3 columns.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Why not? What have you tried? [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve] What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to set the number of GridView columns?

Sure, you could use [`VariableSizedWrapGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid) as `ItemsPanel` of `GridView`. And it has `MaximumRowsOrColumns` property that use to fix the columns or rows for GridView. For example:

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="AliceBlue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                MaximumRowsOrColumns="3">
            </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily achieve that with **UniformGrid** control of **Windows Community toolkit.**
**docs** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid

in this control you can control the number of rows and columns or both as well, just use the nuget package for **Windows Community toolkit controls** and then use it. Goodluck. Also if you want to use databinding with it you can create a custom user control where you can define your DataTemplate and then at runtime you can add new CustomUserControl(); and keep adding them to your uniform grid, this can sole your problem of data binding.

> you also have another new control in new **winui** library called **Repeater** : https://reflectionit.nl/blog/2018/xaml-repeater-control

which us also very flexible  in terms of laying out that can help you as well.

Comment: Great idea but this is more of a Grid than a GridView. For example I can't use Data Binding